# "thank" should followed by bang("!") or period(".")? which is right?

Tags: punctuation, politeness

"thank" should followed by bang("!") or period(".")? which is right?

For example:

> This site vs report bug?What should I to use? I can't find (googled)
>   what something about this. Forgive me,if this is a FAQ question.
>   Thank !

vs

> This site vs report bug?What should I to use? I can't find (googled)
>   what something about this. Forgive me,if this is a FAQ question. Thank
>   .

Comment: It's an exclamation point, not a *bang*...

Comment: @Gerry "bang" is a perfectly acceptable term. It's pretty common amongst programmers.

Comment: @Catija …but not in general usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Thank" is an ordinary verb, but it has two special polite uses. As an ordinary verb, it takes endings of *-s, -ed,* and *-ing* like most verbs. It means to express gratitude:

> Jill forgot to **thank** Bill for giving her a ride from the airport.
>   Jill is **thanking** Bill for the ride right now.
>   Jill **thanked** Bill one day after he gave her a ride.
>   Jill often **thanks** people late.

The polite forms are themselves expressions of gratitude. Each is a whole sentence:

> Thanks.
>   Thanks!
>   Thank you.
>   Thank you!
>   Jill said "Thanks" to Bill.
>   Jill said "Thank you" to Bill.

As an expression of gratitude, you can end the sentence with either an exclamation point or a period. The exclamation point indicates saying it louder; it suggests more enthusiasm and less formality. "Thank you" suggests a little more gratitude than "Thanks."

Notice that "Thank" (without *-s* at the end) is not one of these special polite forms.

Answer (score 0):

Either an exclamation point "!" or a period "." can follow

> Thank**s**!
>   Thank**s**.

it only depends on how enthusiastically you are trying to say

> Thank you! *(thanks!)*
>   Thank you.  *(thanks.)*